# Finding $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}-x$

Tags: limits

In this question,

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}-x=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}-x\right)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}+x}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{9x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}+x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\frac{9x+1}{\sqrt{x^2}}}{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2}}+\frac x{\sqrt{x^2}}}=\frac{-9}{\sqrt{1}-1}$$

I got an answer that is $-9/0$ where that $0$ is just indefinitely approaching $0$. Therefore, I got the answer $-\infty$. However, the correct answer is $+\infty$.

May I know what mistakes have I made?

Comment: If we throw rigour out the window, we can say that the $0$ in the denominator is slightly negative. This cancels the negative part of $-9$. Slightly more rigorously, we see that $\sqrt{x^2+9x+1} < \sqrt{x^2} = -x$, and thus the denominator approaches $0$ from the left. Of course, you should evaluate the limit in the way the answer below did.

Comment: Why do you get $-9$? And where did the other minus sign come from?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur my thought is that I need to divide all of them by sqrt(x^2), which is equal to |x|. With the definition of |x|, if x -> -inf, it gives out -x as answer. So there is a minus sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $y=-x \to \infty$ we obtain

$$\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}-x=\sqrt{y^2-9y+1}+y\to \infty$$

since $\infty + \infty $ is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: Oh thanks I don't know I can do it this way, so by y = -x, it is just like I am doing -(-inf) = +inf?

Comment: @234ff Yes we can always make change of variables to obtain a simpler form. Of course we can also skip this step but in this way things are more clear in my opinion.

Comment: @234ff The key point is that both $\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}$ and $-x$ tend to $\infty$ therefore $$\sqrt{x^2+9x+1}+(-x) \to \infty$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

$\lim_{x \to - \infty } \sqrt{x^2+9x+1 }-x$ = $\lim_{x \to - \infty } - x(\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2 }}+1)$=$-\infty$

Because
$\lim_{x \to - \infty } \frac{9}{x}$=$0$

And
$\lim_{x \to - \infty } \frac{1}{x^2 }=0$